# Google Colab runs out of RAM(12GB) when trying to tf.image.resize dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

```
new_img = []
images = list(df['pixels'])
  
 
for image in images:
  image = image.split()
  new_img.append(image)

new_img = np.array(new_img)
new_img = new_img.astype('float32')/255
new_img = new_img.reshape(df.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
new_img = tf.image.resize(new_img(297,297))
```

In the code above (last line), I am trying to resize the whole dataset (35000 elements).
But Google Colab exhausts all RAM.
Is there any other way to approach this problem, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the last line supposed to do? Why are you calling `new_img`?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I have edited the code. The dataset includes images. I have processed them so they are ready to be included in the model for training. In the last step, I want to resize all images from 48,48 to 297,297. But it runs out of ram because there are many images (around 35000) The code is correct when I resize 1 image it does it. But for the whole dataset, there is not enough computation power, it runs out of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it iteratively with `tf.data.Dataset`. The pictures will only be resized while iterating through the dataset, one batch at a time. So it won't create a new dataset in memory.

```
new_img = np.array(new_img)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(new_img).\
    map(lambda x: tf.resize(x/255, (297, 297)))

print(next(iter(ds)))
```